# Remove the second tooltip in Tree map using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am drawing a treemap using Highcharts in my web app. I am using the latest highcharts CDN. 
I have written a custom tooltip which is working just fine. But I am able to see a second small tooltip. I want to remove the second one. I have not written any code for the second tooltip and that tooltip is visible only for the smaller (shape) data-points.

In the following image you can see the custom tooltip and the other one (small) which I want to remove.

[image: Screenshot of treemap]

Here is my code

```
$.getJSON("URL_TO_GET_DATA_FROM_SERVER", function(json) {

  $('#container').highcharts({
    colorAxis: {
      minColor: '#FF0000',
      maxColor: '#00FF00',
      stops: [
        [0, '#FF0000'],
        [0.50, '#736F6E'],
        [1, '#00FF00']
      ]
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    tooltip: {
      backgroundColor: {
        linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 60],
        stops: [
          [0, '#FFFFFF'],
          [1, '#E0E0E0']
        ]
      },
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#AAA',
      borderRadius: 2,
      formatter: function() {
        return 'Ticker: <b>' + this.point.name + '</b><br></br>Market Cap (JPY M): <b>' + this.point.value.toFixed(2) + '</b><br></br>Percent Change (%): <b>' + this.point.colorValue.toFixed(2) + '</b>';
      }
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'treemap',
      layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
      data: json,
    }]
  });
});
```

Also, if this is browser functionality then please let me know. I am using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way of just removing the elements that are causing this (`<title>` elements) is adding this to your chart options:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function(e) {
            $(".highcharts-data-labels text > title").remove();
        },
        redraw: function(e) {
            $(".highcharts-data-labels text > title").remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Check [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/05mj13dc/) where the last point would've had a title if it was not removed.

Comment: Works likes a charm.